# Loop Through an XML with PHP

Tags: php, xml, parsing

I am trying to loop through this XML file using PHP so that I can display books from 2005 only!

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <bookstore>
      <book category="cooking">
        <title lang="en">Everyday Italian</title>
        <author>Giada De Laurentiis</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>30.00</price>
      </book>
      <book category="children">
        <title lang="en">Harry Potter</title>
        <author>J K. Rowling</author>
        <year>2005</year>
        <price>29.99</price>
      </book>
      <book category="web">
        <title lang="en">XQuery Kick Start</title>
        <author>James McGovern</author>
        <author>Per Bothner</author>
        <author>Kurt Cagle</author>
        <author>James Linn</author>
        <author>Vaidyanathan Nagarajan</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>49.99</price>
      </book>
      <book category="web" cover="paperback">
        <title lang="en">Learning XML</title>
        <author>Erik T. Ray</author>
        <year>2003</year>
        <price>39.95</price>
      </book>
    </bookstore>
```

I am using simplexml_load_string. to covert the code to a string in php.

How would I use php to find books from 2005?

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: Please add the code you have so far to the question. We cannot help without.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along the lines of this?

```
$bookstore = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach($bookstore as $book){
    if($book->year == 2005){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Since you use [SimpleXML](http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php), you should look into [`SimpleXMLElement::xpath`](http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php)

Searching through w3schools.com [XPath Tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp), where this example seems to be from, you will also find an example at [XPath Syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)

```
/bookstore/book[year='2005']
```